# Non-Square Pixel on georeferencing of images using GDAL

Tags: gdal, c++

I have a image in .jpg format. I have some GCP and also know the pixels values of these GCp in that image. Now i trying to convert this image into geotiff. for that I have coded the following lines. But the output seems to be weird. Although the geo information are tagged in the images but the pixels in the output seems to have non-square pixel. Anybody help please???

My code :

```
     GDALDatasetH hSrcDSarray;
     GDALAllRegister();
     hSrcDSarray = GDALOpen("test.jpg", GA_ReadOnly );    
     hDriverarr[i] =  GDALGetDriverByName( "GTiff" );
     GDALDatasetH hDstDSarray;
     char **papszOptions = NULL;
     GDALProgressFunc    pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;

    hDstDSarray= GDALCreateCopy( hDriverarr, "geo.tif", hSrcDSarray, FALSE, papszOptions, pfnProgress, NULL );

    double w=GDALGetRasterXSize( hSrcDSarray ); //get width
    double h=GDALGetRasterYSize( hSrcDSarray ); //get height

    // The GCP and pixels values come from external file

    GDAL_GCP *gcps = NULL;
    gcps = (GDAL_GCP *) malloc(((10000-2)/4)*sizeof(GDAL_GCP) );


    for(int i=0;i<image_output.size();i++){
        gcps[i].dfGCPPixel = image_output[i].x;
        gcps[i].dfGCPLine  = image_output[i].y;

        gcps[i].dfGCPX = GCP_points[i].x;
        gcps[i].dfGCPY = GCP_points[i].y;
        gcps[i].pszId = (char *) malloc( 1000*sizeof(char) );

    }

    double adfGeoTransform[6];
    GDALGCPsToGeoTransform(image_output.size(),gcps,adfGeoTransform,0);

    free(gcps);

    OGRSpatialReferenceH hSRS;
    char *pszSRS_WKT = NULL;

    GDALSetGeoTransform( hDstDSarray, adfGeoTransform );

    hSRS = OSRNewSpatialReference( NULL );
    OSRSetUTM( hSRS, UTM_zone, TRUE );
    OSRSetWellKnownGeogCS( hSRS, CS );
    OSRExportToWkt( hSRS, &pszSRS_WKT );
    OSRDestroySpatialReference( hSRS );

    GDALSetProjection( hDstDSarray, pszSRS_WKT );
    CPLFree( pszSRS_WKT );

    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) hDstDSarray );
```